# Bukkit adding multi lores through split() | everytime player does has \n in config

Tags: java, bukkit

Whenever a player does lore:\ndog the **\n** should add a new loreline so if the so if a player does lore:\ndog1\ndog2(in the config) it should add 2 lores the first one being dog1 and the second one being dog2.

The problem is that it's not even returning the correct lore it's always returning the bottom items lore 50 times by 50 times I mean there would be 50 lines of lores for that both of the items in the config

---

9:46PM
9-7-2015
Question restated:
What i'm trying to do is add a new lore line everytime a player has a \n in there part[1] so if a player has a lore:dog\ndog it makes new lore line because 
"\n" is suppose to grant you a new line!

---

```
public ArrayList<String> lorelist;
    public ItemStack applyLore(ItemStack stack, String name, String lore1)
    {
        ItemMeta meta = stack.getItemMeta();
        meta.setDisplayName(name.replaceAll("&([0-9a-f])", "\u00A7$1"));
        lorelist = new ArrayList();
       // lorelist.add(lore1.replaceAll("&([0-9a-f])", "\u00A7$1"));
        meta.setLore(lorelist);
        stack.setItemMeta(meta);
        return stack;
    }

function test(World world, Player p)
      String labels = "name: lore:";
      String[] parts = labels.split(" ");
      String name = parts[0];
      String lore = parts[1];
      if (b instanceof Chest) {

          if (chest.getInventory().getSize() == 27) {
              if (s.contains("restrict:singlechest")) {
                  if (chance < Integer.parseInt(s.substring(itemchance.length()).split(" ")[2].replace("chance", "").replace("chan", "").replace("ance", "").replace(":", ""))) {

                      chest.getBlockInventory().addItem(applyLore(new ItemStack(Integer.parseInt(s.split(" ")[0]), amountgot),
                          s.substring(name.length()).split(" ")[0].replace("_", " ").replace("ame:", "").replace("e:", ""),
                          s.substring(lore.length()).split(" ")[1].replace("_", " ").replace("lore:", "")));
                      for (int i = lore.length(); i < lore.length(); i++) {
                          lorelist.add(lore.substring(lore.length()).split("\n")[i].replaceAll("&([0-9a-f])", "\u00A7$1").replaceAll("lore", ":"));

                          break;

                      }
                      break;
                  }
              }
          }
}
```

Config

```
    ChestPopulater:
  items:
  - 126 name:&9Thor_Godly_Axe lore:1st_lore_line\n&7second_lore_line chance:99 maxamount:1 restrict:doublechest
  - 276 name:&9testblade lore:dog1\ndog2\ndog3 chance:99 maxamount:1 restrict:singlechest
```

Updates:
9:40PM 9/27/2015
I tried the following still didn't work

```
         for ( int i = 0; i < lore.length(); i++ )
            {
               if ( Integer.toString(i).contains("\n") )
               {
                    lorelist.add(Integer.toString(i).replaceAll("&([0-9a-f])", "\u00A7$1"));
                    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + "Debug");
               }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what is going on with your code correctly, lots of variables just come out of nowhere... However, what I would do, is say `lore` is the string with the lore in it, something like this: `lore:apple\ndog\nHow_are_you`. Also, `item` is the itemstack to add the lores to, `name` is the item name to be added and `endItem` is the finished item with the lores added. Then, this code should work if I understand correctly.

```
ArrayList<String> lorelist = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] lores = lore.split("\n");
for (String addlore : lores) {
    lorelist.add((addlore.replaceAll("&([0-9a-f])", "\u00A7$1")).replaceAll("_", " ");
}
endItem = addInfo(item, name, lorelist);
```

Here is the `addInfo` function.

```
public ItemStack addInfo(ItemStack item, String name, ArrayList<String> lorelist) {
    ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();
    meta.setDisplayName((name.replaceAll("&([0-9a-f])", "\u00A7$1")).replaceAll("_", " "));
    meta.setLore(lorelist);
    item.setItemMeta(meta);
}
```